# Simple Ember.js Test Methods

Tags: javascript, ember.js, integration-testing

I'm reading through [this section](https://guides.emberjs.com/v2.13.0/tutorial/autocomplete-component/#toc_acceptance-tests) of the guide. I'm testing the complex component in the tutorial.

What I'm not understanding is why these two lines exist together, I believe only the first one should.

`fillIn('.list-filter input', 'Seattle');`

`keyEvent('.list-filter input', 'keyup', 69);`

---

In the first line, we fill in the input field which should automatically trigger a filtering of the results. Why are we adding an extra `e` to the field (keycode 69)? It's like we're going to search `Seattlee` (*note the two `e`'s at the end*). Is the `keyEvent` method necessary to activate the triggering of the refresh but it actually doesn't print to the `input` field?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose the keyup event doesn't enter a char. It simply does for its name stands for: fires the key up event. You can press a char on the keyboard and see, that the char is being added before you release the key. I'm sure this is specified somewhere, but I don't know this. My reason is the common sense.

So in order to trigger some functionality in that example, one needs not only to fill the field, but to fire a specific event, to which a js-handler is bound